# Snap to Grid UI in Cappuccino

Tags: drag-and-drop, cappuccino, objective-j

Does anyone know how to do snap-to-grid in Cappuccino? Basically, I have draggable objects which I can drag into a target area. The target view needs to be set up with snap-to-grid feature. I've seen it with Mockingbird, so it's definitely possible.

Any info is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably implement a receiver for the draggingUpdated message and update the position of your drag feedback view to your snap positions. Apple's docs might help: [draggingUpdated](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingDestination_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_7). Just think CP instead of NS.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a try today and follow up. Thanks for your suggestion!